# Debug slow home network

Tags: networking, router, nas, samba, bandwidth

I don't know how to approach this problem. The TL;DR is that my internal home network is "slow". Here is the setup:

- I live in the UK. I have a Sky ER115 router
- Directly plugged into the router (with ethernet), I have a home made NAS. It has 4 high quality disks setup with RAID5. The NAS runs samba. The OS is archlinux
- I have a desktop and a laptop, both running Archlinux. They are connected to the router with Ethernet

When I'm uploading something from my computers to the NAS, the max upload speed I get is 7 MiB. I get about the same download speed. Does that seem normal to you? It seems a bit low to me. I'm basically staying on the local network 192.168.0/8.

The problem is that I don't know how to identify which component limits my bandwidth:

- the cables between my computers and the router (I doubt it)
- the cable between the router and the NAS (doubt it)
- the router not processing the data fast enough?
- the CPU on the NAS struggling with the amount of data?
- the RAID struggling with the amount of data (doubt it)

Would you be able to help me pinpointing the problem please?

Comment: Try another router ?

Comment: My experience is that transfer speed PC-to-PC or to NAS, where the router handles *both* sides of the traffic, is far slower than to the internet. As @harrymc states, another router might be better... or not. One dedicated to the NAS might improve things: https://dongknows.com/best-wi-fi-router-nas-solutions/

Comment: TIL, I didn't know I could replace my Sky router with a modem router. I thought my ISP box was mandatory to access internet. I don't have another modem router, so I just tried a wifi router (but still with ethernet) and I just created a simple network: NAS -> router -> laptop. No internet. I got 11MiB/s. Much better. But still, I'd like to know which component is the limiting factor. E.g, both my NAS and laptop have 1000 Mbps (~250 MB) network cards, so I'm still far from the limit

Comment: Try different cables.